# Is it possible to pull in the contents of a github gist as text from within the javascript browser?

Tags: javascript, github, web, browser, gist

I know you can embed a gist into a static webpage, but while on the static webpage, is there a way to get the contents of that gist in javascript?

Also, embedding it results in it producing a DOM structure, which can be difficult to parse. Looking over the "View Raw" URL, it appears that the URL cannot be easily determined from just the gist hash, since it contains the username in the url...

Has anyone devised a way to make it easy to get the contents of a gist programmatically from the clientside, preferably without having to embed the gist content?

Comment: you mean something like this? `<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jcgregorio/stamp/master/src/stamp.js"></script>`

Comment: "Looking over the "View Raw" URL, it appears that the URL cannot be easily determined from just the gist hash, since it contains the username in the url"

To be more clear, I was thinking of something similar to the rust playground. If you look at their URL: http://play.integer32.com/?gist=82e4ed08d09cc9632abaa3470e848266&version=stable

They provide a gist hash, and determine the file from the *server*. Is there a way to do this from the *client*

Comment: sorry, didn't read your question very thoroughly. it's relatively easy on the server side to get the user name from the hash. If you request `https://gist.github.com/a6378edb420a1c654c5f27bb494ca1c8`, you will get a 302 redirect with the user name included. And then you can just add `/raw` to the end of the redirect location header, and it will give you the raw view. Unfortunately, because of CORS I haven't been able to find a way to do this from the client side. And it won't work with the `/raw` without the username.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by getting the raw text from gist:

https://gist.github.com/sturmenta/2bbfbce1e93fd75cb1f6f9e1663252c8

```
const gistUrl = 'https://gist.github.com/sturmenta/df1c9da1f219c88e996e48f19d57acd3';

const {data, error} = await getGistFirstFileText(`${gistUrl}.json`);

console.log(data);

// result ->
//
// ## some title
//
// some text
```